# Want to display the popup on the selected row in enyo.js

Tags: enyo

I have a repeater In which I am displaying different values.On click of each row I want to display few values.But in the enyo example the content of the popup is popup.....

This content I want to change.I have tried as below

I have the popup-

```
{name: "basicPopup", kind: "enyo.Popup", floating: true, **centered: true,**
        style: "background-color: yellow; padding: 10px", onHide: "popupHidden", components: [
            {content: "Popup..."}
        ]
    },
```

If I am removing **centered:true** all the popups are coming on the left corner.
I want that on the repeater on which i will click the popup should come near that row i mean where i will click popup will come near mouse click.

Please help...

Comment: Is there any swipe function in enyo.js

Comment: You can take a look at enyo.DragAvatar and/or enyo.Slideable. That might help you out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick fiddle I made onto a previous one with a search list.

If you click a list item you'll see I made you a little popup there that'll move along with where you click. I know that the data shown inside the popup is wrong but hey... that's not the point here is it :)

http://jsfiddle.net/joopmicroop/NEYQC/

PS yes there's an enyo swipe function, it's called 'enyo.Slideable', you can view the info here: http://enyojs.com/api/#enyo.Slideable

Comment: When will we start our own enyo chatroom on stackoverflow? :p

Comment: I also want our enyo chat room

Comment: There's an enyo chat on IRC on freenode.net  #enyojs

Comment: Cool, I'll visit some time :)